# Nested form(cocoon gem) not visible in view rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

i made a nested form for my invoice application with the cocoon gem but the form isn't showing on my application but it isn't giving out any errors either.

**_form.html.erb - scaffold form partial**

```
<address>
 <%= f.fields_for :customer do |customer| %>
 <%= render 'customer_fields', f: customer %>
 <%= link_to_add_association 'Add customer',f, :customer %>
 <% end %>
</address>
```

**_customer_fields.html.erb - cocoon partial**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label 'Company Name' %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :company_name, placeholder: 'company name' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label 'Address' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :address_line_1, placeholder: 'address' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label 'Zip Code' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :zip_code %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove customer", f, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>
```

**Invoice.rb model**

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :company
  has_one :customer
  has_many :products


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  validates :number, :currency, :date, :duedate, :btwtotal, :subtotal, :total, presence: true

end
```

**customer.rb model**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :invoice

end
```

**Invoices_controller.rb**

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_invoice, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /invoices
  # GET /invoices.json
  def index
    @invoices = Invoice.all
  end

  # GET /invoices/1
  # GET /invoices/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /invoices/new
  def new
    @invoice = Invoice.new
  end

  # GET /invoices/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /invoices
  # POST /invoices.json
  def create
    @invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.save
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1
  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.update(invoice_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /invoices/1
  # DELETE /invoices/1.json
  def destroy
    @invoice.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to invoices_url, notice: 'Invoice was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_invoice
      @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def invoice_params
      params.require(:invoice).permit(:number, :currency, :date, :duedate, :btwtotal,
                                      :subtotal, :total, :footer, customers_attributes: [:id, :company_name, :address_line_1, :zip_code, :_destroy],
                                      companies_attributes: [:id, :btw_number, :iban_number, :kvk_number, :company_name, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

**Does anybody know how to fix this? Any help would be much much appreciated!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it

```
<address>
 <%= f.object.build_customer if f.object.customer.nil? %>
 <%= f.fields_for :customer do |customer| %>
 <%= render 'customer_fields', f: customer %>
 <%= link_to_add_association 'Add customer',f, :customer %>
 <% end %>
</address>
```

***edit***

in the Luissimo solution was missing to insert invoice_id in `customer` schema

```
rails generate migration AddInvoiceIdToCustomer invoice_id:integer
rake db:migrate
Invoice.first.build_customer
```

Comment: It says; unknown attribute 'invoice_id' for Customer.. maybe i messed up the relationships?

Comment: It's already added in my original post, the second code block.

Comment: rails console run `Customer.new`

Comment: [Rails guide Has One](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association)

Comment: Yeah to be honest i read that already and i tried all kinds of variations with the relations but i still get errors and this relation seemed to make the most sense.. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121417/discussion-between-breno-perucchi-and-luissimo).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your original code, in your controller you should have added:

```
def new
  @invoice = Invoice.new
  @invoice.customer.build
end
```